# Default Directory in Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm new to unix and all this.  In Git Bash it always starts me in directory `~`.  I assume this means for me in windows that'd be `C:\Users\[myusername]` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` is a shorthand for your home directory, i.e., as you said, in gitbash that should be `C:\Users\myUser`.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` the tilde `~` expands to the user's `$HOME` directory. Yes, it's analogous to `C:\Users\[LOGIN]` in Windows.

```
~ $ pwd
/home/efrisch
```